# "Can not use 'await' outside an async function"- Error on React Native Docs

Tags: react-native, async-await, wifimanager

I am new to React Native. Am making this application which needs to turn WiFi on. I used `npm i react-native-wifi-reborn`  package for wifi. While trying out the Example provided with that webpage i got error
**Can not use 'await' outside an async function**
I copied the same code, still faced this error.

**Code**

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
 
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Location permission is required for WiFi connections',
        message:
          'This app needs location permission as this is required  ' +
          'to scan for wifi networks.',
        buttonNegative: 'DENY',
        buttonPositive: 'ALLOW',
      },
);
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    // You can now use react-native-wifi-reborn
} else {
    // Permission denied
}
```

Click [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn) to see the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the developer expect you to use [top-level async/await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) or it's more likely a simple example it's expected from you to handle the asynchronous call properly:

```
const getLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
            {
                title: 'Location permission is required for WiFi connections',
                message: 'This app needs location permission as this is required to scan for wifi networks.',
                buttonNegative: 'DENY',
                buttonPositive: 'ALLOW',
            },
        );

        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            // You can now use react-native-wifi-reborn
        } else {
            // Permission denied
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle unexpected error
    }
}
```

I don't expect React Native to handle top-level async/await so you are bound to wrap your call to PermissionsAndroid.request in an async function.

Comment: As I mentioned, am a beginner in this. Now am getting this `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? The error comes from a bad render.

Comment: I  just missed some import and export functions, its alright now

Answer (score 0):

The error explains itself. You have to use await inside async function.
Try this:

```
  const isPermissionGranted = async() => {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Location permission is required for WiFi connections',
        message:
          'This app needs location permission as this is required  ' +
          'to scan for wifi networks.',
        buttonNegative: 'DENY',
        buttonPositive: 'ALLOW',
      },
);

if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}